# Why General error: 1364 Field 'id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: sql, laravel

what are the possibilities for this error to exist?
or solutions?
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `jfmg_inventario` (`nome`, `data`, `ficheiro`) values (hhhh, 2020-06-27, 96dbe622ec757cbb042d8605172432ff47e777f4.pdf))

Answer (score 1):

You have provided no value for `id` in the `insert` statement.  Hence, the database has to assign one itself.

But, `id` would appear to be declared `not null`, so `NULL` can't be assigned.  And there is no default value or generator for the column.  Typically, an `id` would be auto-generated somehow with an incremental value.  In standard SQL, the declaration would look like:

```
id int generated always as identity primary key,
```

Comment: ho very thaanks